# class circular dependency resolve with inversifyJS

Tags: circular-dependency, inversifyjs

I have tried to understand how to resolve circular dependencies using `InversifyJS` but I'm still having an issue.

I have a class `Leader` which needs to have a `Follower` and the `Follower` instance must be bound to `Leader`. I'm using `lazyInject` from `inversifyJS` but still when `report()` function of follower is executed it sees `leader` property as `undefined`.

Here's follows an example that demonstrates my problem:

```
import { Container, inject, injectable } from "inversify";
import "reflect-metadata";
import getDecorators from "inversify-inject-decorators";

const SYMBOLS = {
  LEADER: Symbol("LEADER"),
  FOLLOWER: Symbol("FOLLOWER"),
};

const container = new Container({
  autoBindInjectable: true,
  defaultScope: "Singleton",
});

const { lazyInject } = getDecorators(container);

@injectable()
class LeaderClass {
  @inject(SYMBOLS.FOLLOWER) follower1!: FollowerClass;
  public sn = "Ldr-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

  public report = () => {
    console.log("Leader:", this.sn);
    console.log("Follower1: ", this.follower1.sn);
  };
}

@injectable()
class FollowerClass {
  @lazyInject(SYMBOLS.LEADER) leader!: LeaderClass;
  public sn = "Flw-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

  public report = () => {
    console.log("Follower:", this.sn);
    console.log("Leader:", this.leader.sn);
  };
}

container.bind<LeaderClass>(SYMBOLS.LEADER).to(LeaderClass);
container.bind<FollowerClass>(SYMBOLS.FOLLOWER).to(FollowerClass);

const leader = container.get<LeaderClass>(SYMBOLS.LEADER);
const follower = container.get<FollowerClass>(SYMBOLS.FOLLOWER);

console.log("--------");
console.log("   ");
console.log(leader.report());
console.log(follower.report());
```

The line:

```
console.log(follower.report());
```

throws an error because `follower.leader` is `undefined`.

Any suggestions on how to solve such situations?

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: @PrasanthRaj I didn't. I believe that lazyInject has a problem. I made sure that I resolved my Circular Dependency. Mainly, declare a 'setXXXXInstance' public method, and when the dependency initiated, then use this to make connection back to it.